# Makefile specify dependency to ignore automatic dependency rule

Tags: makefile

say I have the Makefile

```
p5: p5.py
    . ${SRCDIR}/$^

%.py: clean
    spark-submit ${SRCDIR}/$@ ${SPARK_OPTS}
```

How can I have p5 run without calling the default rule for *.py files?

Comment: Remove the `p5.py` dependency?

Comment: then it wouldnt be dependent on p5.py which it is ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default rule your are mentioning is the `%.py:` rule, then you can simply add an empty rule for `p5.py`:

```
p5: p5.py
    . ${SRCDIR}/$^

p5.py:;

%.py: clean
    spark-submit ${SRCDIR}/$@ ${SPARK_OPTS}
```